# Is there a better way to write this Typescript type for storing api method calls?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to find a way to improve either `GenericActionables` or `Items` so that the name of the api method doesn't need to be added as a `GenericActionables<"nameOfNewMethod">` to the `Actionables` type every time so they are always in sync. Ideas appreciated thank you :)

```js
interface API {
    playSound: (id: string, volume: number) => void,
    playPool: (id: string, randomize: boolean) => void
}

type GenericActionables<T extends keyof API> = {
    method: T,
    params: Parameters<API[T]>
}

// Is there a way to write this in a better way
// as not to have to update this type
// whenever the api gets added functionality so that they are always in sync?
type Actionables =
    GenericActionables<"playSound"> |
    GenericActionables<"playPool">

export const actionables: Actionables[] = [
    {method: "playSound", params: ["quack", 0.8]}, // this should work
    {method: "playSound", params: ["quack", true]}, // this should NOT work
    {method: "playPool", params: ["smack", true]}, // this should work
    {method: "playPool", params: ["smack", 0.8]}, // this should NOT work
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

[Full code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgSSgXigbwFBSmANgQxAGUB7AVwDsATALigAoBLWqAZ2ACdGKBzAGigA3ErjIBbCHQriARhA4BKFAD4hJZgG4sOAiDgkRdJi3ZdeAjvmokxjAF6SoMg7ghWlyVcM0YAvloxQSCgAcQgKeUYAYxgo4EYSCnwZV1YAHgAVKAgAD2BwqlYoAGsIEBIAM1hEVVRMbAlgAAsSFgytbDB8SzFWOjhu-Eb5dPgEAG0MgF1lLX8MQPBoADV8UQh0jNqoDPHS8qrprSDoWPjE5NSUKFX19LQocYBpKG4SssrqhCm6MIiuGJxBJJFIbNJPVS+WYLXJgEgcYBQKKJdhQfBAi6gvqwDEg1LjKbXcbaNCNFosABEeEIpEoVApAi6PWx4wpAEcyOjigyoAAGAB0AA4pr4BAB6MVQZqMIqsFpkXBUKAAd3hxRJZNadCpulp1B5TKGLPZnKi3IEnDIEBF4sl0tl8sVUAAcgB5LKqjjq7CkiDNLVQHWEfQiA2DXp0VmsMRcnmW62iqASqVNGVsR1Kz3e9CaynUvQuMPMyMU6OxgQC4WJ5P29PkJ1uj1qjBTLRAA)

```ts
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
type Actionables = Values<{ [K in keyof API]: GenericActionables<K> }>;
```